# Creating DataFrame in Pandas (Wrong Shape)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a DataFrame in Pandas with the following code:

```
df_coefficients = pd.DataFrame(data = log_model.coef_, index = X.columns, 
columns = ['Coefficients'])
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

Shape of passed values is (5, 1), indices imply (1, 5)

The values and indices are as follows:

Indices =

```
Index([u'Daily Time Spent on Site', u'Age', u'Area Income',
       u'Daily Internet Usage', u'Male'],
      dtype='object')
```

Values =

```
array([[ -4.45816498e-02,   2.18379839e-01,  -7.63621392e-06,
     -2.45264007e-02,   1.13334440e-03]])
```

How would I fix this? I've built the same type of table before and I've never gotten this error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Index and Values arrays have different shapes.  As you can see the Index array has single brackets while the Values array has double brackets.

That way python reads index as having shape (5,1) while the Values array is (1,5).

if you enter Values as you wrote in the question:

```
Values =

array([[ -4.45816498e-02,   2.18379839e-01,  -7.63621392e-06,
 -2.45264007e-02,   1.13334440e-03]])
```

and call Values.shape it returns
    Values.shape
    (1,5)

Instead if you set Values as:

```
Values = np.array([ -4.45816498e-02,   2.18379839e-01,  -7.63621392e-06,
 -2.45264007e-02,   1.13334440e-03])
```

then the shape of Values will be (5,) which will fit with the index array.

Answer (score 0):

Your data has five columns and one row instead of one column and five rows. Just use the transposed version of it with [`.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html):

```
df_coefficients = pd.DataFrame(data = log_model.coef_.T, index = X.columns,
                               columns = ['Coefficients'])
```